# Disabled button not being styled correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to style a button that is disabled, but the styling doesn't take effect, and go back to the old styling. I have cleared my cache, to no avail. I have a button that gets disabled using JavaScript with `document.getElementById("updateAccountButton").disabled = true;`. This aforementioned button also has the class of `btn-signature-green`. Inside my stylesheet, I am trying to set the styling of this button when disabled using:

```
.btn-signature-blue:disabled, .btn-signature-green:disabled, .btn-signature-red:disabled {
    /* styles go here */
}
```

This is because I have other buttons that may have disabled attributes that I want to account for.

Code snippet:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("updateAccountButton").disabled = true;
});
```

```css
/* disabled button */

.btn-signature-blue:disabled, .btn-signature-green:disabled, .btn-signature-red:disabled {
    background-color: #afafaf;
    color: white;
}

.btn-signature-green {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 11px -7px #5fd623;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 11px -7px #5fd623;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 11px -7px #5fd623;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #67e827), color-stop(1, #81de52));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#67e827', endColorstr='#81de52', GradientType=0);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* the green button when hovered over */

.btn-signature-green:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #81de52), color-stop(1, #67e827));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#81de52', endColorstr='#67e827', GradientType=0);
    background-color: #81de52;
    color: black !important;
}

/* the green button when clicked */

.btn-signature-green:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn-signature-green" id="updateAccountButton">disabled button</button>
```

Comment: Can you attach your code snippet?

Comment: @Derek.W The code snippet was added.

Comment: Answer attached.

Comment: thanks. That solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disabled` style is overlapped by the parent style.

- Instead of `background-color`, use `background` on `:disabled` style.
- And the parent button has got `color` style with `!important` so it is needed to set the `color` with `important` on `:disabled` selector style.
- And to disable hover effect when disabled, it is needed to set `pointer-events: none;`.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("updateAccountButton").disabled = "disabled";
});
```

```css
/* disabled button */

.btn-signature-blue:disabled, .btn-signature-green:disabled, .btn-signature-red:disabled {
    background: red;
    color: blue !important;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.btn-signature-green {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 11px -7px #5fd623;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 11px -7px #5fd623;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 11px -7px #5fd623;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #67e827), color-stop(1, #81de52));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #67e827 5%, #81de52 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#67e827', endColorstr='#81de52', GradientType=0);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* the green button when hovered over */

.btn-signature-green:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #81de52), color-stop(1, #67e827));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #81de52 5%, #67e827 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#81de52', endColorstr='#67e827', GradientType=0);
    background-color: #81de52;
    color: black !important;
}

/* the green button when clicked */

.btn-signature-green:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn-signature-green" id="updateAccountButton">disabled button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using two different properties, you are setting a `background` on your button but a `background-color` on the disabled, `background` takes priority so it looks like it doesn't work as you'd expect.

To fix this you just need to use the same properties between disabled and active buttons.